# How to load and use a PARI/GP script in Sage notebook?

Tags: sagemath

I don't know whether this is the correct place to ask such a question, but I am dealing with this problem for a couple of days.

Take for example the script http://math.stanford.edu/~stange/scripts/tate_via_nets.gp.

What I do is: copy the script to a txt file and name it tate_via_nets.gp. Then I go to my sage notebook and choose above the option 'gp'. In the first block I write

\r filename

where filename is the whole path of the file tate_via_nets.gp (so C:....\tate_via_nets.gp) and "evaluate" it. But then I get the error

***   at top-level: read("/home/sage/.sa
  ***                 ^--------------------

*** read: error opening input file:
`C:\Users...\tate_via_nets.gp'.

If you see me doing things wrongly please let me know it :-) 
I am working with sage 4.7.1

Thanks

EDIT: I have changed the "source" of the problem

Comment: There is nothing wrong with asking such a question here.  But, I think you would probably get better/quicker answers if you ask at http://ask.sagemath.org/questions/
There are several people there that know about most aspects of Sage.

Comment: That was my first step :-)
But no one replied (see the fourth last question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do this in a https://cloud.sagemath.com Sage worksheet.  See [this worksheet](https://cloud.sagemath.com/projects/4a5f0542-5873-4eed-a85c-a18c706e8bcd/files/tate.sagews) (login required).  (Since this interface will eventually become the standard Sage Notebook, this answer will eventually be relevant for offline use.  Also, cloud.sagemath didn't exist when you asked your question...)

1. Upload your file to a project: use +New and paste in the URL
2. Make a New Sage worksheet with first cell:

   %default_mode gp

and second cell

```
\r tate_via_nets.gp
```

3. The rest of your worksheet is a full GP worksheet, and the code in that file is available.   (You can use %sage at the top of a cell to temporarily escape back to sage mode.)
4. You can also directly click on tate_via_nets.gp and edit it (I just noticed there's no syntax highlighting for gp scripts, but I'll fix that soon), and the editor has themes, and also a vim/emacs mode if you need that.

[image]

-- William

Answer (score 4):

In https://cloud.sagemath.com do this:

1. Create a project and a new Sage worksheet in the project.
2. Paste in this line and press shift+enter:
       `gp.read(get_remote_file('http://math.stanford.edu/~stange/scripts/tate_via_nets.gp'))`
3. In another cell, type this to confirm that you've loaded the code.

   ```
   %gp
   tate_pairing_alg
   ```
4. Use it -- type %gp at the start of a cell to use gp.

Comment: That solves this concrete problem. But what if I want to use a script that I wrote? I mean when I copy and paste the gp code of tate_via_nets and evaluate it I get an infinite loop ...

Comment: @user1286 Hi, the link does not work anymore. Is it possible for you to update the link? Thanks!

Comment: I've made it so downloading from math.stanford.edu is now allowed so that link works.  I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why does it not work if I copy and paste the code in Sage notebook? If I copy the code to a cell in Sage notebook and evaluate it, it just keeps running. The solution provided by user1286 is okay if I would not have to adjust the code and so on.